# Structure Server Function in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am struggling with my first shiny app and having problems to make it work due to, I think, I am missing out something in the server function.

I have a R script that has two variables (the two reactive values in shiny) that creates a plot (a histogram) and a csv file with two columns (time and mm).

```
library(ggplot2)
**Pdmm** <- 125                 # numeric input in shiny
**IndiceTorrencial** <- 10      # slider between 8 and 12 in shiny 
DuracionAgua <- 24
IntervaloMin <- 60
IntervaloTiempo <- IntervaloMin/60
Intervalos <- DuracionAgua/IntervaloTiempo
t <- seq(1,Intervalos,IntervaloTiempo)
DF <- data.frame(t)
DF$I <- (**Pdmm**/24)*(**IndiceTorrencial**)^(((28^0.1)-(DF$t^0.1))/((28^0.1)-1)) # equation where the reactive values are running
DF$Pacu <- DF$t*DF$I
DF$Pmm <- c(DF$Pacu[1], diff(DF$Pacu, lag = 1))
DF$mm <- c(DF$Pmm[23],DF$Pmm[21],DF$Pmm[19],DF$Pmm[17], DF$Pmm[15],DF$Pmm[13],DF$Pmm[11],DF$Pmm[9],DF$Pmm[7],DF$Pmm[5],DF$Pmm[3],DF$Pmm[1],DF$Pmm[2],DF$Pmm[4],DF$Pmm[6],DF$Pmm[8],DF$Pmm[10],DF$Pmm[12],DF$Pmm[14],DF$Pmm[16],DF$Pmm[18],DF$Pmm[20],DF$Pmm[22],DF$Pmm[24])
ggplot(DF,aes(x=t,y=mm)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill = "dodgerblue",color = "black") + scale_x_continuous(name = "t(h)", breaks = seq(1,24,1)) + scale_y_continuous(name = "mm")
```

My shiny app has, in its UI, a slider, a numeric input and a plot.  It works, I will have time to make something better.

```
ui <- basicPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "coefTo",
              label = h3("Torrentiality Coefficient"),
              value = 10, min = 8, max = 12),
  numericInput(inputId = "PmmS",
               label = h3("Areal Precipitation"),
               value = 100),
  imageOutput("plot")
)
```

The problem is in the server function.  I think I am sure that I have to use a reactive function in order to execute the code and to yield the results (histogram and csv).  Also, to plot the histogram, I have a renderPlot.

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    DuracionAgua <- 24
    IntervaloMin <- 60
    IntervaloTiempo <- IntervaloMin/60
    Intervalos <- DuracionAgua/IntervaloTiempo
    t <- seq(1,Intervalos,IntervaloTiempo)
    DF <- data.frame(t) 
    DF$I <- (input$PmmS/24)*(input$coefTo)^(((28^0.1)-(DF$t^0.1))/((28^0.1)-1))
    DF$Pacu <- DF$t*DF$I
    DF$Pmm <- c(DF$Pacu[1], diff(DF$Pacu, lag = 1))
    DF$mm <- c(DF$Pmm[23],DF$Pmm[21],DF$Pmm[19],DF$Pmm[17], DF$Pmm[15],DF$Pmm[13],DF$Pmm[11],DF$Pmm[9],DF$Pmm[7],DF$Pmm[5],DF$Pmm[3],DF$Pmm[1],DF$Pmm[2],DF$Pmm[4],DF$Pmm[6],DF$Pmm[8],DF$Pmm[10],DF$Pmm[12],DF$Pmm[14],DF$Pmm[16],DF$Pmm[18],DF$Pmm[20],DF$Pmm[22],DF$Pmm[24])
    DFm <- DF$mm

    return(DFm)

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(DFm),aes(x=t,y=mm)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill = "dodgerblue",color = "black") + scale_x_continuous(name = "t(h)", breaks = seq(1,24,1)) + scale_y_continuous(name = "mm")
  })

}
```

When I run this script, I get the shiny app I have the slider and the numeric input, but not the plot getting an error message saying `Error: unused argument (DFm).`  DFm is not created, so I assume that I am placing bad the code from my original script inside the shiny app, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have tried several things to make the server works, but I think that the script never runs inside the shiny app.  I tried to create two reactive functions, one per each reactive value.  I tried to put all the code from my original script out of the shiny leaving just the reactive values inside the shiny code... I tried with observe function as well.
Another problem I have is that I am not sure about the renderPlot.  I am aware that I have to call the reactive function, data, but as I am not sure if it is well made.
I think that my server function is a total disaster.  I have looked for examples in the shiny gallery and in Google, but I do not see something similar to help me.

Could anyone give a tip in order to fix my server function?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `data()` instead of `data(DFm)` in your ggplot

Comment: I did it, in that case I get: Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric.  But the most important is that DFm is not created, the script does not work inside the shiny app.

Comment: Why are you returning only `DFm` instead of `DF` which is actually a dataframe?

Comment: DONE!!!! as simple as change DFm for DF.  I tried with DF, without return(), and it did not work.  Later, I tried to create a new dataframe with the two columns I needed and then I used return().  Now, I cancel DFm and make return(DF) and it works.... many thanks.... several days with headache and it was so easy.....

Comment: Would be good to answer your question and mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of our colleague, I could solve my problem by setting DF, the first data frame I created, in return() inside the reactive function.   Another confusion was how to set the object from the reactive function inside the renderplot.